# How to overlap two absolutely positioned elements?

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="btn" >
            <span>X<span>
            <div class="vertical_line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.btn{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:80px;
        text-align:center;
        position: relative;
    }
   div.vertical_line{
        width:0;
        height:100px;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        position:absolute;
        right:50px;
        z-index:100;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    div.btn span{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:0;
    }
```

Here is the [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/y9d25gxq/)

Can anyone please tell me how to position 'X' in center such that the vertical line and X will overlap each other?

Comment: See this: https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/y9d25gxq/5/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making span text to have absolute position, I have given line to have absolute position, and have placed text in center using text-align : center.

```
 div.btn{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:80px;
        text-align:center;
        position: relative;
    }
   div.vertical_line{
        width:0;
        height:100px;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        position:absolute;
        right:49px;
        z-index:100;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        top : 0;
    }
    div.btn span{
        float:left;
        width : 100%;
        text-align : center;
        z-index:0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following

HTML

```
<div class="btn" >
    <div class="vertical_line"></div>
    <span>X</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.btn{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
  }
div.vertical_line{
    width:0;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    position:absolute;
    right:50px;
    z-index:100;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.btn span{
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Edit : Is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/y9d25gxq/9/